# How are Objective-C classes implemented?

Tags: objective-c

I keep hearing about how Objective-C classes are just C Structs. Can anyone shed more light on how they are actually implemented?

Comment: Nothing special. C Struct with set of methods. Every method is function that have pointer at that struct and method selector in arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep hearing about how Objective-C classes are just C Structs.

Let's talk about objects first.

Objects are not *just* structs. They're structs with a specific layout, which is understood by the Objective-C compiler and runtime. The runtime provides a bunch of C functions that implement things like message passing. The compiler translates Objective-C syntax into calls to those runtime functions. So, a snippet of Objective-C that looks like this:

```
[foo bar:baz];
```

might get translated into equivalent C code:

```
objc_msgSend(foo, sel_bar, baz);
```

where `sel_bar` is the selector that corresponds to `bar:`. `foo` is a pointer to an object, that is, a struct of the form:

```
struct objc_object {
   Class isa;
};
```

There will likely be other instance variables piggybacked on top of that structure, so the struct at `foo` might really look like:

```
struct objc_object {
   Class isa;
   int a;
   float b;
   id c;
};
```

But to be an object that the runtime can work with, a struct really just needs an `isa` pointer as its first member. This points to a class object that defines the class to which `foo` belongs.

Now, a class is also an object -- that is, it's a struct that starts with an `isa` pointer. But classes have additional fields, including the superclass, the class name, list of instance variables, list of methods, and so on. You can see the actual definition in [`objc_class.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/objc-class.h). Look at the [*Objective-C Runtime Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-TPXREF104) to see a list of functions that operate on classes to get a better idea of how that structure can be manipulated by the runtime.

There's a lot more to know about how Objective-C creates objects out of structs, but Apple provides an entire document that explains it, so I'll just refer you to the [*Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 3):

The storage for direct instance variables looks a lot like a C struct; classically it exactly was one and you could manipulate the struct rather than the object directly. That's been removed.

So in the struct you'll have:

- the `isa` pointer, which points to the metaclass;
- a record of the offset within the allocated object to the start of this metaclass' struct members (this is how the fragile base class problem is avoided — the sizes are stored and added together appropriately when the application is loaded); and
- struct-like fields for all your direct instance variables.

Elsewhere in the runtime there will also be at least maps from:

- the metaclass to the method `IMP`lementations for every supported selector;
- the instance to storage for all dynamic properties;
- the instance to associated objects; and
- possibly also from the instance to any `weak` references to it.

In addition there's a hash map for the retain count. The retain count is stored only when it goes above `1` — the first retain is implied.

An exception to a lot of that is tagged pointers. The 64-bit runtime allows very small objects to be stuffed entirely into the pointer. So the pointer is the object storage; the runtime can spot the difference between a real pointer and one that secretly is the object because valid pointers have alignment requirements.

Answer (score -1):

An Objective-C class is actually an object itself.

This is a decent read on the subject: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html

Comment: nice article, but you should include the important bits in your question. otherwise your answer would be a good comment.

Comment: I didn't ask a question...